# Database SQL query error

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb, sql, select

I am trying to run below query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wp_podsrel` WHERE `related_item_id` =$user->ID AND `pod_id` = 17  AND `field_id` = 25";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

But I am getting error.

If I run the Query in phpMyAdmin it is working fine.

Comment: What's the exact error message? And you should use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) instead of including a dynamic value directly in your SQL query.

Comment: Where is `$user` coming from, is this code incomplete? What is the error?

Comment: Assuming `$user` is a object what you are trying to do wont work, you use `"` as your string and `"` can read variables, but `->ID` is not interpeted as expected, you need to wrap it in `{}`, like this `{$user->ID}`

Comment: @Foysal can you update us on what was the error and how did you solve it?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast `$user->ID` does work without the brackets, e.g. *if* the value is a number/string - demo [here](https://3v4l.org/4oVAt) ✌, just like when doing `SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts`. So the error *might* instead be caused by an empty user ID/object (i.e. `WHERE related_item_id = AND ...`) which would result in a MySQL syntax error. 

Comment: @SallyCJ, I forgot to use `global $wpdb;`. Thanks.